# Generating Ring from its Group of Units

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Say $E$ is the group of units of a ring $R$. Is it possible to generate $R$ from $E$? Analogous to how $R$ is generated by its fundamental units.

My hunch says all elements of $R$ should be linear combinations of $E$;  am I completely off base?

Comment: How do you generate $\mathbb{R}[x]$ from its units, the nonzero constants?

Comment: By a linear combination with all coefficients equal to zero. $\mathbb{R} = 0\times r_1 + 0 \times r_2 + \dots$, $r_i \in \mathbb{R^*}$

Comment: That does not make sense. If all coefficients are equal to $0$, the linear combination equals $0$, not “$\mathbb{R}$”. And in any case, even assuming you were correct in getting $\mathbb{R}$ (which you certainly can do), how do you get $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, etc?

Comment: I misunderstood you, that makes perfect sense. Thank you! I wasn't considering that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider any polynomial ring over a field. The group of units will be non-zero constants and they generate a ring that is isomorphic to the field of coefficients but the non-unit element $x$ cannot be generated by them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps similar to what you are asking for,  is the *[group ring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring#Category_theory)* construction.   It is the left adjoint to the group of units functor.  ("Adjunction" corresponds loosely to the notion of "equivalence" in category theory.)